# Checkboxes display?

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

```
JCheckBox special = new JCheckBox ("\nSpecial - $17.95" + "\nMeatball, Sausage, Mushroom, Onion, Pepperoni & Pepper");
```

In this line of code, how do you make the checkbox make the "..." into two lines?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to format it with [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32):

```
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("<HTML>" + "Special - $17.95"
            + "<BR>"
            + "Meatball, Sausage, Mushroom, Onion, Pepperoni & Pepper"
            + "</HTML>");
```

The alternative is to set a custom [ButtonUI](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ButtonUI.html), though that is a considerably more involved approach.

Comment: How Swing supports HTML markup is described here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html - Follow this link for tag meanings: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32